# Escaping apostrophe in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to escape out of some apostrophe's in my JSON.  I know it's not ideal but i append the data to the DOM and call it later in the code.  At the moment i get an error whenever there is an `'` in the data.  I've tried using `replace` and `encodeURI` but just doesnt seem to work.

My code basically looks like:

```
var addItem = function (item, target){
  var obj = $(item).data('obj');
  var obj_string = JSON.stringify(obj);
  target.append("<div data-obj='" + obj_string + "'> Added </div>
}
```

When i inspect the element it breaks when it gets to the apostrophe:

```
{"publisher":"EA","games":[{"game":"Dragon's"}]}
```

Looks like this in the element inspector:

```
{"publisher":"EA","games":[{"game":"Dragon" s"}]}
```

And everything that follows is broken.  Any ideas how i escape it?

I've found lots of ways if it was pureply jquery but with it being in the html it seems to not work.

Comment: You have to escape with a backslash for use in JSON and remove that backslash for use in HTML.

Comment: Why are you throwing it in an HTML attribute when you could store it with `.data()`?

Comment: Build the element the JS way using `document.createElement(...)`. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the escaping and stringification© using `.data()` to set the `obj` to the element directly.

```
$('<div/>').data('obj', obj).text('Added').appendTo(target);
```

Just keep in mind with this method you won't get a data attribute on the actual element itself but the data will be there when you request it with `.data`.

Comment: You can use `.data('obj', obj)` to keep the same naming as OP and to avoid unnecessarily stringifying/parsing the object.

Comment: I've adjusted it. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: No problem, I've adjusted the key name to `obj` as that is what OP uses in the question (`data-obj`).

Comment: I think that does it actually, just removed the data obj from within the div, stuck it on the end and swapped the append round and it works.  Fab answer, thanks Bill

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating your content with a string that already uses single quotes. The concatenated result will most likely be `<div data-obj='Dragon's'>` which is not what you want.

Either escape the single quote when concatenating it (not sure the entity won't be interpreted):

```
.append("<div data-obj='" + obj_string.replace("'", "&#130;") + "'> Added </div>");
```

Or safer, you can build your nodes with jQuery which will give you a native escaping for some performance penalty:

```
.append($("<div>Added</div>").data("obj", obj_string));
```

Comment: Hi, i was trying to do it the first way you said (minimal changes), however it fails at:  
     `function ensureObject(obj) {
         if (typeof obj != 'object') {
             obj = eval('(' + obj + ')');
         };
         return obj;
     };`

Im getting the error illegal token

Comment: Oh I see, I actually wrote an error. You sould HTML escape the quote, not prefix it with a backslash. You should be safer using the second one though as the first one does not handle any character that may break HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than leaving yourself open to XSS, try:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Added"));
div.setAttribute("data-obj",obj_string);
target.append(div);
```